# Firefox understands "display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom;" differently

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a `table` containing several `span`s. I set the height of these `span` dynamically and work in percentages (a sort of bar chart). The container of these `span`s has a fixed height and I need it to remain very much fixed. I also need them to be rendered from bottom up, therefore I set on the container `display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom;`. When the total percentage of the heights is greater that 100%, the content needs to stay hidden. Chrome, Internet Explorer and Opera (the Chrome-like version...) "hide" the content but Firefox changes the hight of the table cell/container([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3e2sD/2/)).

Setting the container to `display:block;` solves the "height growth" problem but does not allow the inner `span`s to be bottom-up rendered.

How can I "fix Firefox"?

HTML structure:

```
<hr/>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> 
                <span class="holder">
                    <span id="first"></span>
                    <span id="second"></span>
                    <span id="third"></span>
                    <span id="forth"></span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td> 
                <span class="holder">

                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr/>
```

CSS ("minified" to save space):

```
td { width:90px; overflow:hidden; padding:0px; background-color:yellow; }
td span.holder { width:89px; height:100px; border:1px solid black; padding:0px;
    background-color:green; display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom; }
span.holder span { display:block; border:1px solid black; }
#first { height:30%; background-color:red; }
#second { height:30%; background-color:blue; }
#third { height:20%; background-color:yellow; }
#forth { height:30%; background-color:cyan; }
```

Edit: In this example, the total percentage equals 110% (with respect to the height of the `holder` `span`). Part of the content does not and should not be displayed. Chrome, Internet Explorer and Opera "hide" part of the `first` `span`, while Firefox expands the `holder` parent to fit the content.

[image: The rendering of the elements in different browsers.]

Answer (score 1):

vertical-align does not matter much here.

You are using `display:table-cell;` for `span.holder`. Now, that results in a table-cell inside a table-cell. What happens from there?

> Any table element will automatically generate necessary anonymous table objects around itself, consisting of at least three nested objects corresponding to a 'table'/'inline-table' element, a 'table-row' element, and a 'table-cell' element.
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes

So, your table-cells actually contain tables themselves, and those tables have one row and one column each.

Let's concentrate on this "table":

```
 <!-- (anonymous table) -->
     <!-- (anonymous tbody) -->
         <!-- (anonymous table-row) -->
            <span class="holder"><!-- table-cell -->
                <span id="first"></span>
                <span id="second"></span>
                <span id="third"></span>
                <span id="forth"></span>
            </span>
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uTmLL/)

Now, how are the heights of these elements calculated?

> The height of a 'table-row' element's box is calculated once the user agent has all the cells in the row available: it is the maximum of the row's computed 'height', the computed 'height' of each cell in the row, and the minimum height (MIN) required by the cells. A 'height' value of 'auto' for a 'table-row' means the row height used for layout is MIN. MIN depends on cell box heights and cell box alignment (much like the calculation of a line box height).
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout

Now, we have height = 100px, MIN = 110px + 8px. So, I think that Firefox is right, <del>even though the specs are not very clear about how *exactly* MIN is determined.</del>
Update: I found it: *"If any of the remaining cells, those aligned at the bottom or the middle, have a height that is larger than the current height of the row, the height of the row will be increased to the maximum of those cells"*

As a "fix", use `display:block;` on `.holder`

Comment: I'll give to Firefox for strictly following the specs. I have tried to set `display:block; overflow:hidden;` but, although it fixes the height problem, the inner spans do not get rendered from bottom up. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: @AndreiV I don't know. It looks like the table layout algorithm is designed to make sure the cells are always large enough for all their content. Maybe there is an alternative solution using CSS3 flex?